# How to view an already created DB in MongoDB Compass

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-compass

I made a database in mongo shell and wanted to visualize it. I am trying to find a way to view it. Is it possible to view a database in mongodb compass which has been created in mongo shell.

Comment: It is not clear where the database was created, in Compass you should be able to see it. It occurred to me that I did not visualize a database in Compass because I had no collection created within it. Create a collection and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a collection within the database to view it in Compass.

Regards.